# Dynamically find parent object from belongs_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails

An example schema is "book belongs_to library"

```
r = Book.reflect_on_all_associations(:belongs_to).first
```

The above would give the first reflection. I can then do "r.name" to get "library" (well, assuming no other belongs_to).

So my question is... If I wanted to dynamically access the "Library" class, how would I do that?

I don't want to manually use "Library.all" (etc), since I'm trying to make it a generic thing.

My initial attempt is something like this:

```
r.name.singularize.classify.constantize
```

But that seems awkward.... is there a more proper way?

Answer (score 1):

I just tried this in my console:

```
k = Post.reflect_on_all_associations(:belongs_to).first.active_record
# => User
k.first
# => returns the first user
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
r.class.name.constantize
```

Comment: Ah, better. Am I doing it right generally, though?  reflect_on_all_associations seems cool but low level? Is it the only way if you want to be generic and not refer to the parent models by their name?

Comment: I think so, yes. That's how I would do it.